# Wordpress link hover colors

Tags: css, wordpress, hyperlink, colors, hover

this is the css I have in my `<style>`:

```css
a {
  transition: color 0.18s ease, background-color 0.18s ease, border-color 0.18s ease;
  outline: none;
  color: #161616;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover, a:focus {
  color: #D6D6D6;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Then my link is black, and grey on hover. But when I put a color in `entry content a` like so:

```css
.entry-content a {
    color: #E5C9CC;
}
```

Then my link is just pink, and there is no gray hover and I don't know why.

I don't want all the links on my blog to be pink, only the links in my entries need to be pink with gray hover.

Comment: Have a look at css specificity, your problem is that your lower style is more specific than the hover style so it is overwriting it.  You would either have to add `!important` to the hover (I would suggest against this unless you want it to be for all links) or add an entry for the hover of `.entry-content a `

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```css
.entry-content a {
    color: #E5C9CC;
}

a {
  transition: color 0.18s ease, background-color 0.18s ease, border-color 0.18s ease;
  outline: none;
  color: #161616;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover, a:focus {
  color: #D6D6D6;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Link #1</a><br />
<a href="#">Link #2</a>
<div class="entry-content">
 <a href="#">Link into div</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, like this

```css
.entry-content a {
     color: #161616;
}
.entry-content a:hover {
    color: #D6D6D6;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a {
  transition: color 0.18s ease, background-color 0.18s ease, border-color 0.18s ease;
  outline: none;
  color: #161616;
  text-decoration: none;
}
 .entry-content a {
    color: #E5C9CC;
 }

a:hover, a:focus, .entry-content a:hover, .entry-content a:focus {
  color: #D6D6D6;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

The order and how specific are the selectors is really important. If you specify the hover style to apply also to the `entry-content`, it will work